# Not able to retrieve list of files from container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

**Problem**

Error when I call the below GET api.

Does it have to do with that `sr=d and sdd=4` in the url? I have another url where `sr=c` and has no `sdd` and that works when I make a GET request.

**Endpoint GET Request**

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/xxx/yyy/zzz/xxx/yyy/?sp=rl&st=2022-08-01T12:19:00Z&se=2022-10-01T12:19:00Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=d&sig=xxxxxx&sdd=4&comp=list&restype=container
```

**Error**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidUri</Code>
    <Message>The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
RequestId:1f1dda37-c01e-0118-457d-b24d16000000
Time:2022-08-16T14:35:50.3635803Z</Message>
</Error>
```

**Expected Output**

Able to list the files in the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your request URL to

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/xxx?sp=rl&st=2022-08-01T12:19:00Z&se=2022-10-01T12:19:00Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=d&sig=xxxxxx&sdd=4&comp=list&restype=container&prefix=yyy/zzz/xxx/yyy/
```

Above URL assumes that your container name is `xxx` and you want to list blobs in `yyy/zzz/xxx/yyy/` virtual folder.

Also, your signed resource should be `c` (for blob container).

Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs.

Comment: thanks for replying, I will try this, but the URL does have `d` and not `c`, and the url I was given works well in "Azure Storage Explorer" when I select "ADLS Gen 2 container"

Comment: I have upvoted your solution for now, will accept if it works for me

Comment: My answer is applicable for non-ADLS accounts and when ADLS accounts are used as regular storage account. Can you try to use ADLS specific URL (`https://myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net` instead of `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net`) and see if the same URL works.

Comment: I did try my url after your suggested changes (the prefix part, dfs instead of blob and `c` instead of `d`) I get `{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidUri",
        "message": "The request URI is invalid.\nRequestId:0ed8f3fb-901f-0062-027f-b1710e000000\nTime:2022-08-16T14:52:12.6663556Z"
    }
}`

Comment: this works, I had to add the prefix and not change anything, thanks a bunch